# Не могу вписать 0 в Json файл и ошибка в коде Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Всем привет!
У меня возникла ошибка в коде.
У меня не записывается 0 в json файл.
Вот сам код:

```
@client.command()
async def рег(ctx, Id, *, name):
    message = ctx.message 
    if not message.author.bot:
        with open('player.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        a = 0

        await update_data(ctx, users, message.author,message.guild, Id, name, a)
      
        with open('player.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await client.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(ctx, users, user,server, Id, name, a):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['Id'] = Id
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['name'] = name 
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['match'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win']  = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win_rate'] = users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win'] / users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose']
            role = user.guild.get_role(937373473242771516)
            await user.add_roles(role)
            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Info', description = f'твоё ID: ' + Id + "\nТвой ник: " + name + '\nЕсли есть ошибка напиши администрации (vila#1390)!\nПриятной игры на нашем Faceit!' ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['Id'] = Id
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['name'] = name
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['match'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win']  = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win_rate'] = users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win'] / users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose']
            role = user.guild.get_role(937373473242771516)
            await user.add_roles(role)
            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Info', description = f'твоё ID: ' + Id + "\nТвой ник: " + name + '\nЕсли есть ошибка напиши администрации (vila#1390)!\nПриятной игры на нашем Faceit!' ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Когда участник пишет F-рег (свой ID) (свой ник) то в json файл добавляется его профиль с такими значениями как ID NAME ELO OLD_ELO MATCH WIN LOSE WIN_RATE. Но в MATCH WIN LOSE WIN_RATE должно изначально иметь значение 0.

Но появляется ошибка: **discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
**

Кто может помочь, скажите или как сделать что-бы F-рег засунуть в on_message(message) или другое решение проблемы.

и еще, почему в

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
```

def check(x,y,z) работают по очереди и как это исправить.

Вот весь код:

```
TOKEN = settings['TOKEN']

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents) 

filename = 'player.json'


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'], intents=intents)
client.remove_command( 'help' )

channelID = 938114259601219644
channelID1 = 938138361342885948
channelID2 = 938138361342885948

members = []
################################################################################################

@client.event # Означает для выполнения евента после запуска.
async def on_ready():
    print(" Бот подключён ") #Выводит в консоль то что бот запустился с верменем
    await client.change_presence( status = discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Activity( type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name = "v1la Faceit bot | moderator") ) 


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)

    # only work if it is the client
    if payload.member.id == client.user.id:
        return

    if payload.message_id == 937307086197518336 and reaction.emoji == '':
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="RU")
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
        role1 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='EU')
        await payload.member.remove_roles(role1)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member)   
    if payload.message_id == 937307086197518336 and reaction.emoji == '':
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='EU')
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
        role1 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='RU')
        await payload.member.remove_roles(role1)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member)


@client.command()
async def рег(ctx, Id, *, name):
    message = ctx.message 
    if not message.author.bot:
        with open('player.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        a = 0

        await update_data(ctx, users, message.author,message.guild, Id, name, a)
      
        with open('player.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await client.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(ctx, users, user,server, Id, name, a):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['Id'] = Id
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['name'] = name 
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['match'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win']  = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win_rate'] = users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win'] / users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose']
            role = user.guild.get_role(937373473242771516)
            await user.add_roles(role)
            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Info', description = f'твоё ID: ' + Id + "\nТвой ник: " + name + '\nЕсли есть ошибка напиши администрации (vila#1390)!\nПриятной игры на нашем Faceit!' ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['Id'] = Id
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['name'] = name
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo'] = 300
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['match'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win']  = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win_rate'] = users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win'] / users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose']
            role = user.guild.get_role(937373473242771516)
            await user.add_roles(role)
            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Info', description = f'твоё ID: ' + Id + "\nТвой ник: " + name + '\nЕсли есть ошибка напиши администрации (vila#1390)!\nПриятной игры на нашем Faceit!' ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)


@client.command()
async def profile(ctx,member: discord.Member):
    user = member
    with open('player.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['Id']
    exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['name']
    elo = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['elo'] 
    o_elo = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo'] 
    match = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['match'] 
    win = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['win'] 
    lose = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['lose'] 
    win_rate = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['win_rate']

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "", description = "" ,color = discord.Color.green())
    embed.add_field(name=f"Info", value="Name: {}\nID: {}".format(exp, lvl,) , inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Elo", value="elo: {}\nold_elo: {}".format(elo, o_elo) , inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Matchs", value="all match: {}\nwins: {}\nlose: {}".format(match, win, lose) , inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"win rate", value="{}".format(win_rate), inline=False)
    embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)





@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel != None:
        if after.channel.id == 937716652047466606:
            category = after.channel.category
            
            channel2 = await member.guild.create_voice_channel(
                name = f'Поиск матча', 
                user_limit=10,
                category = category,
            )


            role = member.guild.get_role(role_id = 937717442111746098)
            role3 = member.guild.get_role(role_id = 937373489768304731)
            await member.add_roles(role)    

            await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect = True)
            await member.move_to(channel2)



            def check(x, y, z): return len(channel2.members) <= 2

            await client.wait_for('voice_state_update', check = check)         
            await channel2.edit(name = "Поиск матча")
            await channel2.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=937029793864622100), connect = True)
            voice_channel_list1 = member.guild.voice_channels
            guild = member.guild
            for member in guild.members:
                members.append(member)
            for k in members:
                await k.remove_roles(role)
                await k.remove_roles(role3)
                #list the members if there are any in the voice channel
            #getting the members in the voice channel
            for voice_channels in voice_channel_list:
       
                if len(voice_channels.members) >= 0:
                    if len(voice_channels.members) >= 3:
                        for i in voice_channels.members:
                            await i.add_roles(role3)
                    else:
                        for i in voice_channels.members:
                            await i.add_roles(role)

            def check(x, y, z): return len(channel2.members) == 3

            await client.wait_for('voice_state_update', check = check)         
            await channel2.edit(name = "Игроки набраны, идет матч")
            await channel2.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=937029793864622100), connect = False)
            voice_channel_list2 = member.guild.voice_channels
            guild = member.guild
            for member in guild.members:
                members.append(member)
            for k in members:
                await k.remove_roles(role)
                await k.remove_roles(role3)
                #list the members if there are any in the voice channel
            #getting the members in the voice channel
            for voice_channels in voice_channel_list:
       
                if len(voice_channels.members) >= 0:
                    if len(voice_channels.members) >= 3:
                        for i in voice_channels.members:
                            await i.add_roles(role3)
                    else:
                        for i in voice_channels.members:
                            await i.add_roles(role)
                            
            def check(x, y, z): return len(channel2.members) == 0

            await client.wait_for('voice_state_update', check = check) 
            voice_channel_list = member.guild.voice_channels
            await channel2.delete() 
            guild = member.guild
            for member in guild.members:
                members.append(member)
            for k in members:
                await k.remove_roles(role)
                await k.remove_roles(role3)
                #list the members if there are any in the voice channel
            #getting the members in the voice channel
            for voice_channels in voice_channel_list:
       
                if len(voice_channels.members) >= 0:
                    if len(voice_channels.members) >= 3:
                        for i in voice_channels.members:
                            await i.add_roles(role3)
                    else:
                        for i in voice_channels.members:
                            await i.add_roles(role)
            
                                  

       
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author
    if message.channel.id == channelID:
        if not message.author.bot:
       
            print('function load')
            with open('player.json','r') as f:
                users = json.load(f)
                print('file load')
            await add_experience(users, message.author, 1702, message.guild)
            await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)
            with open('player.json','w') as f:
                json.dump(users, f)
        await client.process_commands(message)
        role55 = message.guild.get_role(role_id = 938114033624682528)
        await user.remove_roles(role55)

    if message.channel.id == channelID1:
        if not message.author.bot:
            print('function load')
            with open('player.json','r') as f:
                users = json.load(f)
                print('file load')
            await r_experience(users, message.author, 20, message.guild)
            await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)
            with open('player.json','w') as f:
                json.dump(users, f)
        await client.process_commands(message)
        role55 = message.guild.get_role(role_id = 938138248981655572)
        await user.remove_roles(role55)
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)

    

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo'] = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['elo']
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['elo'] += exp
async def r_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo'] = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['elo']
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['elo'] -= exp



async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['elo']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['o_elo']
  lvl_end = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['elo']
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':

    if lvl_end <= 800:
        role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
        await user.add_roles(role1)


    if lvl_end <= 950:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.add_roles(role2)

    if lvl_end <= 1100:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.add_roles(role3)
    
    if lvl_end <= 1250:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)        
            role4 = user.guild.get_role(938343518294925323)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.remove_roles(role3)
            await user.add_roles(role4)
      
    if lvl_end <= 1400:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)        
            role4 = user.guild.get_role(938343518294925323)        
            role5 = user.guild.get_role(938343561504653332)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.remove_roles(role3)
            await user.remove_roles(role4)
            await user.add_roles(role5)
      
    if lvl_end <= 1550:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)        
            role4 = user.guild.get_role(938343518294925323)        
            role5 = user.guild.get_role(938343561504653332)     
            role6 = user.guild.get_role(938343570694352897)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.remove_roles(role3)
            await user.remove_roles(role4)
            await user.remove_roles(role5)
            await user.add_roles(role6)

      
    if lvl_end <= 1700:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)        
            role4 = user.guild.get_role(938343518294925323)        
            role5 = user.guild.get_role(938343561504653332)     
            role6 = user.guild.get_role(938343570694352897)     
            role7 = user.guild.get_role(938343682791317515)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.remove_roles(role3)
            await user.remove_roles(role4)
            await user.remove_roles(role5)
            await user.remove_roles(role6)
            await user.add_roles(role7)
        
    if lvl_end <= 1850:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)        
            role4 = user.guild.get_role(938343518294925323)        
            role5 = user.guild.get_role(938343561504653332)     
            role6 = user.guild.get_role(938343570694352897)     
            role7 = user.guild.get_role(938343682791317515)
            role8 = user.guild.get_role(938343755570905118)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.remove_roles(role3)
            await user.remove_roles(role4)
            await user.remove_roles(role5)
            await user.remove_roles(role6)
            await user.remove_roles(role7)
            await user.add_roles(role8)
        
    if lvl_end <= 2000:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)        
            role4 = user.guild.get_role(938343518294925323)        
            role5 = user.guild.get_role(938343561504653332)     
            role6 = user.guild.get_role(938343570694352897)     
            role7 = user.guild.get_role(938343682791317515)
            role8 = user.guild.get_role(938343755570905118)
            role9 = user.guild.get_role(938343830053330985)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.remove_roles(role3)
            await user.remove_roles(role4)
            await user.remove_roles(role5)
            await user.remove_roles(role6)
            await user.remove_roles(role7)
            await user.remove_roles(role8)
            await user.add_roles(role9)
    if lvl_end <= 20000:
            role1 = user.guild.get_role(938343282742820874)
            role2 = user.guild.get_role(938343343274987530)    
            role3 = user.guild.get_role(938343399843561532)        
            role4 = user.guild.get_role(938343518294925323)        
            role5 = user.guild.get_role(938343561504653332)     
            role6 = user.guild.get_role(938343570694352897)     
            role7 = user.guild.get_role(938343682791317515)
            role8 = user.guild.get_role(938343755570905118)
            role9 = user.guild.get_role(938343830053330985)
            role10 = user.guild.get_role(938343745479376936)
            await user.remove_roles(role1)
            await user.remove_roles(role2)
            await user.remove_roles(role3)
            await user.remove_roles(role4)
            await user.remove_roles(role5)
            await user.remove_roles(role6)
            await user.remove_roles(role7)
            await user.remove_roles(role8)
            await user.remove_roles(role9)
            await user.add_roles(role10)


##################################################################################################
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Все нужные библиотеки импортированы и скачаны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, в этой строке происходит деление на `0`:

```
users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win_rate'] = users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win'] / users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose']
```

Можно сделать так, что если вдруг `LOSE` равно `0`, то пусть делится на `1` и ошибки не будет:

```
users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win_rate'] = users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['win'] / (users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['lose'] or 1)
```

Вообще можно было бы вынести `users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]` в отдельную переменную и записать гораздо короче:

```
user_data = users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]
user_data['win_rate'] = user_data['win'] / (user_data['lose'] or 1)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, надеюсь сработает

Comment: @ʏ9ᴅᴇʀ Учтите, что эта строка у вас не один раз в коде встречается

Comment: Проверил, теперь все работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое!